Autotransformer Voltage Ratio Limit
What is an autotransformer voltage ratio practical limit? I understand the power transformers used in utility transmission and distribution. I am an Amateur radio operator, and as a group, we use a lot of autotransformers in the HF range of 2 to 50 MHz because insertion loss is lower than conventional voltage transformers. I know there is a practical voltage ratio limit, but I am unsure what that limit is and why.
Most of the conventional advantages of autotransformers disappear at RF. Since power is limited to radio transmitters, safety concerns are no longer present. The copper advantage is nullified because RF does not require many windings on a toroid core made from ferrite materials. For example, a 1:9 voltage ratio = 1:3 turn ratio, 9 turns for an autotransformer, or 12 turns for a conventional.
The number one priority for an RF transformer is efficiency. Generally, autotransformers offer the highest efficiency, but there is a limit. Anything higher than 1:9 is done with conventional winding because it is more efficient than an autotransformer. For example, a 1:49 voltage ratio is a turn ratio of 1:7. On a 2.4-inch toroid core, it requires 3 primary turns and 21 secondary turns.
So, at some point, the efficiency drops below that of a conventional transformer. I have heard 1:16 is the limit, but I have nothing to back it up.

The usual (well, not so much usual anymore) ignition coil is an autotransformer with a winding ratio of 1:30 to 1:60. It is made as an autotransformer just to simplify the wiring, one hardly saves much winding in this case.

The shared winding has to have a progressively thicker conductor as the ratio increases.  As the ratio increases the 1/(n-1) of the autotransformer that is shared in the higher voltage side is a diminishing fraction of the copper cost. The benefit of common reference in autotransformer is sometimes a drawback.

There is no hard limit.
An autotransformer ratio close to unity is very much more efficient than an isolating transformer, because so much of the winding is shared.
As the ratio increases, the benefit of re-using the portion of common winding becomes less and less.
At some point, the difficulty of making and using the common connection, and the loss in flexibility of not having isolation, outweighs the small saving in copper. A 4:1 transformer might be available in isolating and auto-transformer versions. In a 64:1, an isolating transformer serves both uses.
You would need to put yourself in the component manufacturer's position, and ask yourself what would be cost effective to make and market. You may well choose a different ratio at which to stop making autotransformers available, if you weight the efficiency, versatility, and number of lines to market differently.

Thank you Neil, I edited my question for clarity. Amateur radio RF transformers tend to be DIY because they are simple and change priorities.

According to this video by Joel Teaches Electrical, due to safety concerns, auto-transformer voltage ratios in the power distribution system are generally limited to 3:1.
Watch (at least) from 7:10 - 7:50.

Thank you. I understand the safety limitations when working with utility transformers. However, that does not apply to standard RF transformers. RF transformers used in Amateur radio are primarily used to match antenna impedances to the transmitter and receiver. A common autotransformer is 1:9  to match a 50-ohm transmitter to a 450-ohm antenna. Other typical ratios are 1:49 and 1:64, done with voltage transformers. So, the upper limit in this application is not a safety concern; it is something else I don't understand.

I apologize. I misunderstood your question.

No worries Math. Thanks for your input.
